# java.io.UTFDataFormatException while reading file entry name

Tags: java, file, offset, datainputstream, packing

Im trying to "pack" several files (previously inside a jar archive) in another single non-jar file by using DataInputStream / DataOutputStream.

The idea was:

```
    First int = number of entries
    
    First UTF is the first entry name
    
    Second Int is entry byte array length (entry size)

    Then repeat for every entry.
```

The code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        test();

        System.out.println("========================================================================================");

        final DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\randomJarOut")));

        for (int int1 = dataInputStream.readInt(), i = 0; i < int1; ++i) {
            final String utf = dataInputStream.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Entry name: " + utf);
            final byte[] array = new byte[dataInputStream.readInt()];
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; ++j) {
                array[j] = dataInputStream.readByte();
            }
            System.out.println("Entry bytes length: " + array.length);
        }

    }
```

Unpacking original & packing to new one:

```
private static void test() throws Throwable {
    JarInputStream stream = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\randomJar.jar")));
    JarInputStream stream1 = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\randomJar.jar")));

    final byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    final DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\randomJarOut")));

    int entryCount = 0;
    for (ZipEntry entry; (entry = stream.getNextJarEntry()) != null; ) {
        entryCount++;
    }

    outputStream.writeInt(entryCount);

    for (JarEntry entry; (entry = stream1.getNextJarEntry()) != null; ) {
        int entryRealSize = stream1.read(buffer);
        if (!(entryRealSize == -1)) {
            System.out.println("Writing: " + entry.getName() + " Length: " + entryRealSize);

            outputStream.writeUTF(entry.getName());
            outputStream.writeInt(entryRealSize);

            for (int len = stream1.read(buffer); len != -1; len = stream1.read(buffer)) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Apparently im able to unpack the first entry without any problems, the second one and others:

```
Entry name: META-INF/services/org.jd.gui.spi.ContainerFactory
Entry bytes length: 434
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 279
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:656)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at it.princekin.esercizio.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:29)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54384', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this? Why is this working for the first entry but not the others?

Comment: I don't know how you're managing to read at all from a *jar* file with a `FileInputStream`/`DataInputStream`. Even if it were not compressed I don't see how that would work, *unless* it's not a jar at all…

Comment: the original file is a jar, thats why im using JarInputStream to unpack the jar and getting every entry bytes & name.

Comment: I'm referring to *`final DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\randomJarOut.jar")));`*

Comment: thats not anymore a jar file, thats the packed result. i just gave the .jar to understand its the output of the original jar

Comment: Well it certainly confused me ;). Shouldn't *`int entryRealSize = stream1.read(buffer);`* be `int entryRealSize = entry.getSize();`?

Comment: unfortunatly entry.getSize() always returns -1, thats why i had to use `read();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on this is that the jar file (which in fact is a zip file) has a [Central Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29#Central_directory_file_header) which is only read with the ZipFile (or JarFile) class.
The Central Directory contains some data about the entries such as the size.

I think the ZipInputStream will not read the Central Directory and thus the ZipEntry will not contain the size (returning -1 as it is unknown) whereas reading ZipEntry from ZipFile class will.

So if you first read the size of each entry using a ZipFile and store that in a map, you can easily get it when reading the data with the ZipInputStream.

[This page](https://zetcode.com/java/zipinputstream/) includes some good examples as well.

So my version of your code would be:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class JarRepacker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        JarRepacker repacker = new JarRepacker();
        repacker.repackJarToMyFileFormat("commons-cli-1.3.1.jar", "randomJarOut.bin");
        repacker.readMyFileFormat("randomJarOut.bin");
    }
    
    private void repackJarToMyFileFormat(String inputJar, String outputFile) throws Throwable {
        int entryCount;
        Map<String, Integer> sizeMap = new HashMap<>();
        try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(inputJar)) {
            entryCount = zipFile.size();
            zipFile.entries().asIterator().forEachRemaining(e -> sizeMap.put(e.getName(), (int) e.getSize()));
        }

        try (final DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile))) {

            outputStream.writeInt(entryCount);

            try (ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputJar)))) {
                ZipEntry entry;
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                while ((entry = stream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                    final String name = entry.getName();
                    outputStream.writeUTF(name);
                    final Integer size = sizeMap.get(name);
                    outputStream.writeInt(size);
                    //System.out.println("Writing: " + name + " Size: " + size);

                    int len;
                    while ((len = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                }
            }
            outputStream.flush();
        }
    }

    private void readMyFileFormat(String fileToRead) throws IOException {
        try (DataInputStream dataInputStream
                     = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToRead)))) {

            int entries = dataInputStream.readInt();
            System.out.println("Entries in file: " + entries);
            for (int i = 1; i <= entries; i++) {
                final String name = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                final int size = dataInputStream.readInt();
                System.out.printf("[%3d] Reading: %s of size: %d%n", i, name, size);
                final byte[] array = new byte[size];
                for (int j = 0; j < array.length; ++j) {
                    array[j] = dataInputStream.readByte();
                }
                // Still need to do something with this array...
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this answer is the cleanest. Just 2 needed methods, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, probably, lies in that you are mixing not reciprocal read/write methods:

1. The writer method writes with `outputStream.writeInt(entryCount)` and the main method reads with `dataInputStream.readInt()`. That is OK.
2. The writer method writes with `outputStream.writeUTF(entry.getName())` and the main method reads with `dataInputStream.readUTF()`. That is OK.
3. The writer method writes with `outputStream.writeInt(entryRealSize)` and the main method reads with `dataInputStream.readInt()`. That is OK.
4. The writer method writes with `outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len)` and the main method reads with `dataInputStream.readByte()` several times. WRONG.

If you write an array of bytes with `write(buffer, offset, len)`, you must read it with `read(buffer, offset, len)`, because `write(buffer, offset, len)` writes exactly `len` physical bytes onto the output stream, while `writeByte` (the counterpart of `readByte`) writes a lot of metadata overhead about the object type, and then its state variables.

### Bugs in the writer method

There is also a mayor bug in the writer method: It invokes up to three times `stream1.read(buffer)`, but it just uses once the `buffer` contents. The result is that the real size of file is actually written onto the output stream metadata, but it is followed by just a small part of the data.

If you need to know the input file size before writing it in the output stream, you have two choices:

- Either chose a large enough buffer size (like 204800) which will allow you to read the whole file in just **one read** and write it in just **one** write.
- Or either separate read from write algorithms: First a method to read the whole file and store it in memory (a byte[], for example), and then another method to write the byte[] onto the output stream.

### Full fixed solution

I've fixed your program, with specific, decoupled methods for each task. The process consists in parsing the input file to a memory model, write it to an intermediate file according to your custom definition, and then read it back.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Throwable
{
    File inputJarFile=new File(args[0]);
    File intermediateFile=new File(args[1]);
    List<FileData> fileDataEntries=parse(inputJarFile);
    write(fileDataEntries, intermediateFile);
    read(intermediateFile);
}

public static List<FileData> parse(File inputJarFile)
    throws IOException
{
    List<FileData> list=new ArrayList<>();
    try (JarInputStream stream=new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputJarFile)))
    {
        for (ZipEntry entry; (entry=stream.getNextJarEntry()) != null;)
        {
            byte[] data=readAllBytes(stream);
            if (data.length > 0)
            {
                list.add(new FileData(entry.getName(), data));
            }
            stream.closeEntry();
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public static void write(List<FileData> fileDataEntries, File output)
    throws Throwable
{
    try (DataOutputStream outputStream=new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output)))
    {
        int entryCount=fileDataEntries.size();

        outputStream.writeInt(entryCount);

        for (FileData fileData : fileDataEntries)
        {
            int entryRealSize=fileData.getData().length;
            {
                System.out.println("Writing: " + fileData.getName() + " Length: " + entryRealSize);

                outputStream.writeUTF(fileData.getName());
                outputStream.writeInt(entryRealSize);
                outputStream.write(fileData.getData());
            }
        }
        outputStream.flush();
    }
}

public static void read(File intermediateFile)
    throws IOException
{
    try (DataInputStream dataInputStream=new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(intermediateFile)))
    {
        for (int entryCount=dataInputStream.readInt(), i=0; i < entryCount; i++)
        {
            String utf=dataInputStream.readUTF();
            int entrySize=dataInputStream.readInt();
            System.out.println("Entry name: " + utf + " size: " + entrySize);
            byte[] data=readFixedLengthBuffer(dataInputStream, entrySize);
            System.out.println("Entry bytes length: " + data.length);
        }
    }
}

private static byte[] readAllBytes(InputStream input)
    throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer=new byte[4096];
    byte[] total=new byte[0];
    int len;
    do
    {
        len=input.read(buffer);
        if (len > 0)
        {
            byte[] total0=total;
            total=new byte[total0.length + len];
            System.arraycopy(total0, 0, total, 0, total0.length);
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, total, total0.length, len);
        }
    }
    while (len >= 0);
    return total;
}

private static byte[] readFixedLengthBuffer(InputStream input, int size)
    throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer=new byte[size];
    int pos=0;
    int len;
    do
    {
        len=input.read(buffer, pos, size - pos);
        if (len > 0)
        {
            pos+=len;
        }
    }
    while (pos < size);
    return buffer;
}

private static class FileData
{
    private final String name;

    private final byte[] data;

    public FileData(String name, byte[] data)
    {
        super();
        this.name=name;
        this.data=data;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public byte[] getData()
    {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunatly i tried that also, but isnt working, the result still the same :(

Comment: Your code actually works for me with a jar i know not to be corrupt

Comment: im probably missing something, i tried your code but still giving the same issue.. can you provide the fixed part of the code?

Comment: @DonaldC.Spencer I've fixed and tested the whole program successfully. Most important of it is to make separated, decoupled methods for each task.